# What are the advantages of using btrfs snapshots over rsnapshot in a backup scenario

Tags: backup, btrfs, luks, rsnapshot

Currently I use rsnapshot to backup data from one encrypted ext4 drive to another. My system opens a LUKS container on each drive and runs rsnapshot according to an hourly schedule. I'm intrigued by btrfs's built in snapshot feature, and I'm curious if it can be used in place of my current setup (assuming of course I reformat the drives). Are there any obvious issues I'm failing to realize? Can my current setup be improved by using btrfs, is it faster for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

btrfs is a copy-on-write filesystem with many features (like error detection and correction, transparent compression, snapshots, sub-volumes, etc) that make it slower than a traditional filesystem.

However, btrfs snapshots are very light-weight and take almost no time to make.   And using `btrfs send ... | btrfs receive` (or `btrfs send | ssh remote_host btrfs receive`) is much faster than using `rsync` or `rsnapshot` or any other method that needs to compare the files on sender and receiver.

Those file comparisons aren't necessary when sending a snapshot because the exact differences between one snapshot and another are already known (they're inherent to the snapshot) so the changed blocks can just be sent to the receiver as a continuous binary stream - no comparisons of file timestamps or contents is needed.

In short, the overall filesystem performance will be slower, but backups will be **much** faster.

I use `zfs` instead of `btrfs`, which has a very similar snapshot & send/receive mechanism.  When I switched from `rsync` to `zfs send` for my backups, it reduced the run-time for an incremental backup down from several hours to several minutes.

I backup all machines on my local network to a "backup" pool on my main file-server.  It had gotten to the point that the `rsync` backups weren't completing before cron triggered the next day's backup.  With multiple simultaneous backups running at all times, the performance of the server was abysmal, and it required constant manual intervention (mostly killing rsync processes) to bring it back to a usable state.   The switch to `zfs send` was the difference between having a usable file-server and an unusable one.  Now I rarely ever need to even think about it, it just works.  At most every year or two I clear out ancient snapshots on the backup pool (I aggressively auto-expire snapshots on the hosts being backed up, but much less aggressively on the backup pool), which can take a long time if I've let the backup pool retain a million or two snapshots.

As for whether it can replace your current setup or not, I recommend creating a btrfs testing VM with two btrfs pools and experiment with making snapshots and sending them from one pool to the other.  Or multiple testing VMs so you can experiment with `btrfs send`ing a snapshot stream over `ssh`.

I would not recommend switching until you are very familiar and comfortable with how btrfs snapshots and btrfs send/receive work.

In fact, make some ZFS VMs too so you can get a feel for the differences.

VMs are great for trying out new stuff before you decide if you want to use it.  Reading docs is essential, but there's nothing like getting your hands dirty if you really want to understand how something works.

---

BTW, transparent compression can offset much of the performance penalty between using a fs like btrfs or ZFS and a more traditional fs like ext4 or xfs, depending on your workload.

- If fs performance is the only or most important thing for you, then use `xfs` - it's the clear winner, by far.
- If you need/want snapshots, snapshot send/recv, compression, ECC, sub-volumes etc then use either ZFS or btrfs.
- IMO, the only real reason to use btrfs instead of ZFS is that btrfs is in the mainline linux kernel while ZFS probably never will be due to the license conflict between CDDL and GPL.  For ZFS, you have to compile and install the kernel module...which is trivially easy with a zfs-dkms module.
- If you're using Ubuntu then you can use ZFS out of the box, they don't think the license issue is that big a deal - IMO they're wrong about that, but it's unlikely they'll be sued by Oracle.
- Also, one thing that may be of interest to you since you use LUKS is that ZFS can optionally encrypt any dataset ("sub-volume" in btrfs terminology.  Kind of like a combined LV + filesystem in LVM terminology).   I've never used either LUKS or ZFS's encryption, so I can't tell you how they compare.
- I don't really see much reason to use ext4 these days, except that it's pretty much the default for most distros. There's no advantage, no compelling reason to use it.
- Finally, don't be tempted by de-duplication with ZFS.   It sounds like a great idea in theory but what it means in practice is that the de-dupe table needs to be held in RAM so you're reducing your need for more very cheap drives and replacing it with a need for more very expensive RAM.   This is, with a few exceptional use-cases (like running hundreds or thousands of the same VM image), a poor bargain - that RAM would be better used for running programs or caching disks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the obvious issue is...

rsnapshot if ideally configured is copying from one disk to another, so if your data disk goes fubar you are ok and you can restore from a separate backup.  And that backup volume (i.e. different disk) does not need to reside in the same server, rsnapshot can happen over a network connection.

btrfs is all happening on the same disk or volume, if that goes fubar and that's all you have then you are s.o.l.  If it's all on one disk, that's bad.  Using raid5 or raid6 is a good start but you are still highly susceptible to simple file system corruption which raid does not protect against, not to mention fire or water or any other "disaster" at that specific location.

I suspect btrfs would inherently be faster as its snapshot process is happening automatically, versus the time it takes rsnapshot to read from your data volume, the time it takes to write that data over whatever that connection method is to the backup volume, and then the time necessary to put that data to disk on the backup volume.  If its separate disks but in the same server then it can be very fast, but if rsnapshot is going across a network to some other location then that can be a significant penalty.

Using a synology nas they offer either ext4 or btrfs as the file system choice, and I was basically told by them ext4 is faster.  I believe ext4 is faster than btrfs generally speaking, but it of course matters what and how you will be using the file system whether than difference is significant.

Comment: It is possible to send btrfs snapshots to an external volume or remote system via SSH. The operations do not have to take place on the same disk or volume. This is the crux of my question.